# Runtime policy does not allow execution of resource named 'glimpse_config'

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, glimpse

I tried add glipse to the webapi project, but I always get error "Runtime policy does not allow execution of resource named 'glimpse_config'."

How can I fix it ?
How disable this policy ?

Comment: @Thiago_Espanta says: 
Please check if you have the following configuration on the web.config: `<glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd"></glimpse>`

Comment: worked for me. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the web.config file inside your web application project, ensure that the following setting is added somewhere under the 'configuration' XML element, i.e.

```
<configuration>
....other config

<glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd"></glimpse>

</configuration>
```

This also requires the following namespace reference if you don't have it already which should be placed within the 'configSections' element:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
      ... other config
      <section name="glimpse" type="Glimpse.Core.Configuration.Section, Glimpse.Core" />
  </configSections>
</configuration>
```